# Navbar drop down menu item in pug is not working

Tags: html, pug, bootstrap-5

The navigation bar is shown on top of the page as expected. But, when I try to click on one of the drop down menus items (Items, Brands, or Categories), it does not open the drop down options.

[Navbar screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xULC0.png)

pug file:

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
  head
    title= title
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    link(href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous")
    script(src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous")  
  body
    div(class='container-fluid')
      div(class='row')
        block topbar
          nav(class='navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark')
            a(class="navbar-brand" href="/catalog") Home
            button(class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation")
             span(class="navbar-toggler-icon")
            div(class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent")
              ul(class="navbar-nav mr-auto w-100 justify-content-around")
                li(class="nav-item dropdown")
                  a(class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false") Items
                  ul(class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown")
                    li
                      a(class="dropdown-item" href="/catalog/items") All items
                    li
                      a(class="dropdown-item" href="/catalog/Item/create") Create new item
                li(class="nav-item dropdown")
                  a(class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false") Brands
                  ul(class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown")
                    li
                      a(class="dropdown-item" href="/catalog/brands") All brands
                    li
                      a(class="dropdown-item" href="/catalog/brand/create") Create new brand
                li(class="nav-item dropdown")
                  a(class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false") Categories
                  ul(class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown")
                    li
                      a(class="dropdown-item" href="/catalog/categories") All categories
                    li
                      a(class="dropdown-item" href="/catalog/category/create") Create new category
```

This is the same pug code converted to HTML

.................................................................

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"> </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark"><a class="navbar-brand" href="/catalog">Home</a><button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto w-100 justify-content-around">
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Items</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/catalog/items">All items</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/catalog/Item/create">Create new item</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Brands</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/catalog/brands">All brands</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/catalog/brand/create">Create new brand</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Categories</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/catalog/categories">All categories</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/catalog/category/create">Create new category</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bootstrap 5, options by default have the **data-bs-** prefix. So in your markup you could change data-toggle to **data-bs-toggle** and data-target to **data-bs-target**.

See the working code:

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark"><a class="navbar-brand" href="/catalog">Home</a><button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto w-100 justify-content-around">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Items</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/catalog/items">All items</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/catalog/Item/create">Create new item</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Brands</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/catalog/brands">All brands</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/catalog/brand/create">Create new brand</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Categories</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/catalog/categories">All categories</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/catalog/category/create">Create new category</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The dropdown menu item do have the attribute you specified. I fixed the button attribute you mentioned and it still does not solve the issue

Comment: May you update your snippet? It still shows the classes **data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"**.

Comment: I have updated the snippet

Comment: I see it working fine. May you develop on what's left to solve?

Comment: I finally found why the code is not working. This change was not what fixed the issue. The issue was the Helmet middleware that is was using in my app.js file. After removing the middleware I had the code was working just fine. Thanks for the help!